# wall heaters running even after thermostat reaches set temp

Tags: hvac

I have wall heater units connected to a thermostat.  The room reaches temperature but heaters keep running.  Have reprogrammed thermostat several times without success

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. You're going to have to give us some more info than that. Please [edit] your post to include the make/model of the heaters and thermostat(s). How are they connected to each other? I presume these are electric baseboard heaters, or are they hot water radiators? Lots of unanswered questions, and the possible solutions will vary _greatly_ depending on your answers.

Comment: Details about the system might help. I have answered based on a system I have experience with that behaves that way as a matter of normal operation.

Comment: How long do they keep running for? For energy efficiency they might run for a few minutes to extract the last bit of heat.   We could help a lot more if you described what sort of heating system you have.

Comment: Some non-digital thermostats sometimes have a delay before it signals gas valve to shut. Does te furnace eventually shut off? It may be time for new thermostat.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hot water fan units it's common for the hot water to be controlled by the thermostat, but the fan in the unit is controlled by a switch that turns it on when the water to the unit gets hot, and off when the water gets cool, so the fan may run for some time after the circulation is shut off. *i.e.* that would be considered normal behavior.